Whether NO or NO2 is released on treatment of galena with nitric acid?
I am still a student and recently I encountered a question which asked about the reaction of $\ce{HNO3}$ with galena. From what I know, whether $\ce{NO, NO2, N2O}$ etc. will be evolved would depend on different concentrations of $\ce{HNO3}$ and also some other cases. Since the concentration wasn't mentioned I just assumed the reaction would be similar to reaction of metal with concentrated $\ce{HNO3}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ would be released. But the given answer key to the question is $\ce{NO}$. Can someone please explain?
There was a similar question on the site but the answers to it did not specifically explain why NO is released instead of NO2 ..

This question is similar to: Which gases(or gas) are evolved in the leaching of Galena(PbS) with conc. Nitric acid?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@NilayGhosh well I did check the answers to that post/question but it did not specifically explain why NO is released instead of NO2...

The relative amounts of $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ produced depends on the concentration of $\ce{HNO3}$, as you mentioned in your question. What else do you want to know ?

As already mentioned in the other question, leaching behavior is different with the concentration of nitric acid and the temperature of the reaction. $\ce{PbS}$ is insoluble in cold dilute acid. It is readily dissolved in hot dilute $\ce{HNO3}$ giving lead nitrate and free sulfur, the latter being the result of a secondary reaction between the liberated $\ce{H2S}$ and further nitric acid, also generating $\ce{NO}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\ce{PbS + 2HNO3 &->  Pb(NO3)2 + H2S} &|\times 3 \tag{1}\\
\ce{3H2S + 2HNO3 &-> 3S + 4H2O + 2NO}& \tag{2}\\
\hline
\ce{3PbS +8HNO3 &-> 3Pb(NO3)2 + 3S + 2NO + 4H2O}
\end{align}
$$
Some portion of $\ce{PbS}$ is oxidized by the nitric acid into $\ce{PbSO4}$
But if the mixture is boiled, sulfur is oxidized by the nitric acid to sulfate, which immediately forms white lead sulfate along with generating $\ce{NO}$
$$
\begin{align}
\ce{S + 2HNO3 &-> SO4^2- + 2H+ + 2NO} \tag{3}\\
\ce{PbS + SO4^2- + 2H+ &-> PbSO4 + H2S} \tag{4}\\
\hline
\ce{PbS + S + 2HNO3 &-> PbSO4 + 2NO + H2S}
\end{align}
$$
At strong concentration of nitric acid, galena is not dissolved but directly coverts into lead sulfate as precipitate.
$$\ce{3PbS + 8HNO3 -> 3PbSO4 + 8NO + 4H2O}\tag{5}$$
In both cases, $\ce{NO}$ is evolved as a result of oxidation of sulfur/sulfur species.
References:

A Manual of Chemical Analysis: Qualitative and Quantitative by George S. Newth, 1906
Vogel Qualitative Analysis by G. Svehla, 5th ed.

